# What usable alternatives to XML syntax do you know?

Tags: xml, syntax, yaml

For me **usable** means that:

- it's being used in real-wold
- it has tools support. (at least some simple editor)
- it has human readable syntax (no angle brackets please)

Also I want it to be as close to XML as possible, i.e. there must be support for attributes as well as for properties. So, no [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) please. Currently, only one matching language comes to my mind - [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Do you know any other alternatives?

Comment: JSON doesn't match. It doesn't support "attributes as well as properties".

Comment: Get a pencil and paper, and try to mockup a syntax that supports attributes, elements and hierarchy. Now see how human readable your attempts are.

Comment: @basel: you'll then get python

Comment: @makapuf I think you misspelled Lisp.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

YAML is a 100% superset of JSON, so it doesn't make sense to reject YAML and then consider JSON instead.  YAML does everything JSON does, but YAML gives so much more too (like references).

I can't think of anything XML can do that YAML can't, except to validate a document with a DTD, which in my experience has never been worth the overhead.  But YAML is so much faster and easier to type and read than XML.

As for attributes or properties, if you think about it, they don't truly "add" anything... it's just a notational shortcut to write something as an attribute of the node instead of putting it in its own child node. But if you like that convenience, you can often emulate it with YAML's inline lists/hashes. Eg:

```
<!-- XML -->
<Director name="Spielberg">
    <Movies>
        <Movie title="Jaws" year="1975"/>
        <Movie title="E.T." year="1982"/>
    </Movies>
</Director>


# YAML
Director: 
    name: Spielberg
    Movies:
      - Movie: {title: E.T., year: 1975}
      - Movie: {title: Jaws, year: 1982}
```

For me, the luxury of not having to write each node tag twice, combined with the freedom from all the angle-bracket litter makes YAML a preferred choice.  I also actually like the lack of formal tag attributes, as that always seemed to me like a gray area of XML that needlessly introduced two sets of syntax (both when writing and traversing) for essentially the same concept.  YAML does away with that confusion altogether.

Comment: Suppose your semantics did not need a <Movies> child? I.e. you wanted <Director> elements to have a list of children such as <Movie> or perhaps other events in the director's life (eg <Married>..). YAML can't do that without create a pointless extra layer - in your case <Movie>. I can see situations where you want that sort of thing and where YAML is in adequate or verbose. It is also what the OP actually said they wanted.

Comment: There is a good reason to reject YAML and to prefer JSON, which is complexity of the former and ease of implementation of the latter.

Answer (score 12):

[JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a very good alternative, and there are tools for it in multiple languages. And it's really easy to use in web clients, as it is native javascript.

Comment: I already mentioned JASON, do you know some alternative to it ?

Answer (score 11):

## TL;DR

Prolog wasn't mentioned here, but it is the best format I know of for representing data.  Prolog programs, essentially, describe databases, with complex relationships between entities.  Prolog is dead-simple to parse, whose probably only rival is S-expressions in this domain.

## Full version

Programmers often "forget" what XML actually consists of.  Usually referring to a very small subset of what it is.  XML is a very complex format, with at least these parts: [DTD schema language](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/), [XSD schema language](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/), [XSLT transformation language](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/), [RNG schema language](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/relax-ng/spec-20011203.html) and [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/) (plus XQuery) languages - they all are part and parcel of XML standard.  Plus, there are some apocrypha like [E4X](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/Ecma-357.pdf).  Each and every one of them having their own versions, quite a bit of overlap, incompatibilities etc.  Very few XML parsers in the wild implement all of them.  Not to mention the multiple quirks and bugs of the popular parses, some leading to notable security issues like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_external_entity_attack .

Therefore, looking for an XML *alternative* is not a very good idea.  You probably don't want to deal with the likes of XML at all.

YAML is, probably, the second worst option.  It's not as big as XML, but it was also designed in an attempt to cover all bases... more than ten times each... in different and unique ways nobody could ever conceive of.  I'm yet to hear about a properly working YAML parser.  Ruby, the language that uses YAML a lot, had famously [screwed up](https://www.sitepoint.com/anatomy-of-an-exploit-an-in-depth-look-at-the-rails-yaml-vulnerability/) because of it.  All YAML parsers I've seen to date are copies of [libyaml](https://bitbucket.org/xi/libyaml), which is itself a hand-written (not a generated from a formal description) kind of parser, with a code which is very difficult to verify for correctness (functions that span hundreds of lines with convoluted control flow).  As was already mentioned, it completely contains JSON in it... on top of a handful of Unicode coding techniques... inside the same document, and probably a bunch of other stuff you don't want to hear about.

JSON, on the other hand, is completely unlike the other two. You can probably write a JSON parser while waiting for downloading JSON parser artefact from your Maven Nexus.  It can do very little, but at least you know what it's capable of.  No surprises.  (Except some discrepancies related to character escaping in strings and doubles encoding).  No covert exploits.  You cannot write comments in it.  Multiline strings look bad.  Whatever you mean by distinction between properties and attributes you can implement by more nested dictionaries.

Suppose, though you wanted to right what XML wronged... well, then the popular stuff like YAML or JSON won't do it.  Somehow fashion and rational thinking parted ways in programming some time in the mid seventies.  So, you'll have to go back to where it all began with McCarthy, Hoare, Codd and Kowalski, figure out what is it you are trying to represent, and then see what's the best representation technique there is for whatever is that you are trying to represent :)

Comment: Very good answer, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I have found [S-Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression) to be a great way to represent structured data. It's a very simple format which is easy to generate and parse. It doesn't support attributes, but like YAML & JSON, it doesn't need to. Attributes are simply a way for XML to limit verbosity. Simpler, cleaner formats just don't need them.

Answer (score 5):

Jeff wrote about this [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001114.html) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001139.html).  That should help you get started.

Answer (score 5):

There is [AXON](http://intellimath.bitbucket.org/axon) that cover the best of XML and JSON. Let's explain that in several examples.

**AXON could be considered as shorter form of XML data.**

XML

```
<person>
   <name>Frank Martin</name>
   <age>32</age>
 </person>
```

AXON

```
person{
  name{"Frank Martin"}
  age{32}}
```

XML

```
<person name="Frank Martin" age="32" />
```

AXON

```
person{name:"Frank Martin" age:32}
```

**AXON contains some form of JSON.**

JSON

```
{"name":"Frank Martin" "age":32 "birth":"1965-12-24"}
```

AXON

```
{name:"Frank Martin" age:32 birth:1965-12-24}
```

**AXON can represent combination of XML-like and JSON-like data.**

AXON

```
table {
  fields {
    ("id" "int") ("val1" "double") ("val2" "int") ("val3" "double")
  }
  rows {
    (1 3.2 123 -3.4)
    (2 3.5 303 2.4)
    (3 2.3 235 -1.2)
  }
}
```

There is available the python library [pyaxon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyaxon) now.

Comment: Is Axon still active and supported in any way? The documentation is pretty minimal, and the code looks like it hasn't been touched in 6 or 7 years. It looks really promising, but I'm a little weary of jumping on something that will crash and burn under me after a while...

Comment: Right. This library was not used for a long time, because it did not arouse much interest. Perhaps in the near future this will be revised and a new version will be released that is adapted to the latest pythons. (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: That's what it looked like (I couldn't compile it). I ended up moving to JSON for this application. I liked the AXON concepts, though, and may consider it for future projects if it gets revived. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You're demands are a bit impossible.. You want something close to XML, but reject probably the closest equivalent that doesn't have angle-bracket (YAML).

As much as I dislike it, why not just use XML? You shouldn't ever have to actually read XML (aside from debugging, I suppose), there are an absurd amount of tools about for it.

Pretty much anything that isn't XML isn't going to be as widely used, thus there will be less tool support.

JSON is probably about equivalent, but it's pretty much equally unreadable.. but again, you shouldn't ever have to actually read it (load it into whatever language you are using, and it should be transformed into native arrays/dicts/variables/whatever).

Oh, I do find JSON *far* nicer to parse than XML: I've used it in Javascript, and the simplejson Python module - about one command and it's nicely transformed into a native Python dict, or a Javascript object (thus the name!)

Comment: Please read my question carefully. YAML doesn't support attribute at all.

Comment: AFAIK, nor does JSON, but your question says that JSON is a valid alternative for your use.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend JSON ... but since you already mentioned it maybe you should take a look at [Google protocol buffers](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2008/07/protocol-buffers-googles-data.html).

Edit: Protocol buffers are made to be used programatically (there are bindings for c++, java, python ...) so they may not be suited for your purpose.

Comment: I've heard about Google protocol buffers but never bother to take a look at them. Did you have any experience with that Google stuff?

Comment: No practical experience. We use JSON at work but I had read the docs of Google's protocol buffers a bit and thought they might be worth it whenever JSON won't be suited enough.

Comment: Do they, now? @KenBloom

Answer (score 2):

I think [Clearsilver](http://www.clearsilver.net/) is a very good alternative. They even have a comparison page [here](http://www.clearsilver.net/docs/compare_w_xmlxslt.hdf) and a list of [projects](http://www.clearsilver.net/examples.hdf) that use it

Answer (score 2):

YAML is extremely fully-featured and generally human-readable format, but it's Achilles heal is complexity as demonstrated by the Rails vulnerabilities we saw this winter.  Due to its ubiquity in Ruby as a config language Tom Preston-Werner of Github fame stepped up to create a sane alternative dubbed TOML. It gained massive traction immediately and has great tool support.  I highly recommend anyone looking at YAML check it out:

https://github.com/mojombo/toml

Answer (score 2):

For storing code-like data, [LES](http://loyc.net/les/) (Loyc Expression Syntax) is a budding alternative. I've noticed a lot of people use XML for code-like constructs, such as build systems which support conditionals, command invocations, sometimes even loops. These sorts of things look natural in LES:

```
// LES code has no built-in meaning. This just shows what it looks like.
[DelayedWrite]
Output(
    if version > 4.0 {
        $ProjectDir/Src/Foo;
    } else {
        $ProjectDir/Foo;
    }
);
```

It doesn't have great tool support yet, though; currently the only LES library is for C#. Currently only one app is known to use LES: [LLLPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664785/A-New-Parser-Generator-for-Csharp). It supports "attributes" but they are like C# attributes or Java annotations, not XML attributes.

In theory you could use LES for data or markup, but there are no standards for how to do that:

```
body {
    '''Click here to use the World's '''
    a href="http://google.com" {
        strong "most popular"; " search engine!"
    };
};

point = (2, -3);
tasteMap = { "lemon" -> sour; "sugar" -> sweet; "grape" -> yummy };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're allergic to angle brackets, then JSON, [HDF](http://www.clearsilver.net/docs/man_hdf.hdf) (ClearSilver), and [OGDL](http://ogdl.sourceforge.net/) are the only ones I know offhand.

After a bit of googling, I also found a list of alternatives here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20060325012720/www.pault.com/xmlalternatives.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, JSON and YAML are exactly equivalent in data structure terms. YAML just has less brackets and quotes and stuff. So I don't see how you are rejecting one and keeping the other.

Also, I don't see how XML's angle brackets are less "human readable" than JSON's square brackets, curly brackets and quotes.

Comment: As a person who wrote tons of those brackets, I can say there is a HUGE difference. You you don't know how YAML is different from XML, please read wikipedia articles linked in the question text.

Comment: I know how YAML and XML are different. What I don't know is how YAML and JSON are different, except that the former is more human readable, but you reject it, and the latter has square brackets, curly brackets and quotes, and you said it was OK.

Answer (score 0):

There are truly plenty of alternatives to XML, but the main problem with many of them seems to be that libraries might not be available for every language of choice and the libraries are relatively laborious to implement.

Parsing a tree structure itself might not be that pleasant, if compared to key-value pairs, e.g. hash tables. If a hash table instance meets the requirement that all of its keys are strings and all of its values are strings, then it's relatively non-laborous to implement hashtable2string() and string2hashtable().

I've been using the hash table serialization in AJAX between PHP and JavaScript and the format that I've developed, is called ProgFTE (Programmer Friendly text Exchange) and is described at:

http://martin.softf1.com/g/n//a2/doc/progfte/index.html

One can find a Ruby version of the ProgFTE implementation as part of the Kibuvits Ruby Library:
http://rubyforge.org/projects/kibuvits/